Animated shortfilm (maybe) or game cutscene/trailer where an asteroid transform into a tentacled monster?
I remember from a long time ago (probably in the 1995-2005 era) a short animated movie (unless it was a game cutscene or trailer) in which a spaceship slowly passes by an asteroid (or moon, but rather an asteroid), which for a moment seems to take the shape of a skull, and then slowly transforms into a sphere shaped tentacled monster that grabs and crushes the spaceship.

Could this be "Knights of Sidonia"?
It's a Japanese anime series quite more recent that the provided time interval (season 1 aired in 2014, season 2 in 2015, then a compilation movie, and a concluding movie released in 2021), but the other details kinda match.
The story follows a population of humans in a far future travelling in a large spaceship that looks like an asteroid pierced by a metallic prism. A group of young soldiers fight in mechas. The enemies are alien creatures matching you sphere shaped tentacled monster definition and they have shape-shifting capabilities. In one of the first episodes one of them, after crushing a mecha, assumes the shape of the (deceased) female pilot head.
Its peculiar cel-shaded 3D graphics style could explain why you thought it could be a game cutscene/trailer.



